# TFS 2018 AzureFileCopy task version 2

Tags: azure, tfs

I use the AzureFileCopy task to copy build results to an azure storage. To use it with the static website (container '$web'), i need to use version 2 of the AzureFileCopy task. But in the build definition i can only select version "1.*"

How can i install the newer version of this task?

I use TFS2018 Update 3.2

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is available in Azure DevOps Server 2019 RC2 if you want to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Install node.js and npm
run:
`npm install -g tfx-cli`

Once it is installed, launch node.js command prompt.

run
`tfx login`

input service url and PAT (created from webportal)

run 
`tfx build tasks upload --task-path (e.g. .\AzureFileCopyV2) --service-url https://<tfs url>` (include collection on 2017 I believe)

You might be prompted for your PAT again. Input it and upload the file.

Answer (score 0):

Officially, the built-in tasks are only upgraded when you upgrade the server to it's next Update version or Major version. TFS 2018 update 3.2 is the latest update version for TFS 2018 and given that Azure DevOps Server 2019 (the new name for TFS) has just been released, I expect that no new versions of the tasks will ship for TFS 2018 update 4 should it ever see the light.

### Workaround

> **CAUTION** this may cause issues when upgrading to another server version at a later stage, may require newer versions of the Azure Pipelines Agent and can put you in an unsupported state.

You can clone the [Azure Pipelines Tasks](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/) repo, build it locally and then use [tfx-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tfx-cli) to upgrade the built-in tasks in your server [as described by LiveFastYoung](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55384675/736079).

```
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks.git
cd azure-pipelines-tasks
npm install
npm run-script build --task AzureFileCopyV2

npm install tfx-cli@latest -g
cd tasks AzureFileCopyV2
tfx build tasks upload --task-path . --service-url {{https://server/tfs/collection}}
```